# Make a website load with browser zoomed at 1:1

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, mobile, single-page-application

I know similar questions have been asked but I have found no solution of any kind for my issue. I am building a mobile web app that has a google map embedded into it. My issue is that if a user double taps on it to try and zoom the map (which basically takes up the whole screen) it, in some cases, zooms in the browser instead of the map. Then the trouble is that the user is unable to zoom back out. Using two fingers to zoom out passes the event to the map instead of the browser and then renders the web app useless. Reloading the page keeps it zoomed in. I understand that browsers typically don't allow the script to change the browser zoom because 'controlling UI for the user is a bad idea' but in this situation I am saving the user. I don't want to do it while viewing the page, just either on load (the user will undoubtedly try and reload when they can't view/use the web app right) or on a button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge after quite a bit of googling on this, it is indeed not possible to change the browser zoom once the page has loaded. However, you can make a request to the browser, prior to loading the DOM, to start at a certain zoom level and/or to limit the zoom. Here is the meta tag I used to do this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
```

I think for the most part the attributes are pretty self explanatory, and if you are needing more/different control I'm sure there are more options to play with. Also, keep in mind this is also entirely up to the browser on whether or not it wants to follow this.